# How can I query for duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that targets several tables. I've discovered that I have a lot of duplicate pages I need to be fixed. For example, the URL mysite/africa won't display because there are half a dozen instances of 'africa' in my database tables. It's a little hard to track all the dupes down, because I have thousands of rows of data in several database tables.

So can anyone tell me how I can modify this query so it displays ONLY items that are dupes? Better yet, is there a way to display the number of dupes for each item? For example, say I six instances of 'africa' in my database and two instances of 'georgia', it would display this:

africa (6)
georgia (2)

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, Name, 'landform' AS TypeX FROM  gw_geog_landforms WHERE Dupe = '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, Name, 'uno' AS TypeX FROM gw_geog
) AS Combined");
 $stm->execute(array(
 ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using LIMIT 1 will limit the result to 1 SELECT:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, Name, 'landform' AS TypeX FROM  gw_geog_landforms WHERE Dupe = '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, Name, 'uno' AS TypeX FROM gw_geog
) AS Combined
WHERE Combined.URL LIKE :XURL LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Oh, so if I add "limit 1," then I don't need to worry about duplicates? That's an unexpected good tip; thx. However, I'd still like to learn how to display duplicates in my database, so I can work with them. Just displaying a simple list of duplicates would be a big help.

Comment: yes. but if you have a unique identifier for example user id and you add it on the WHERE usr_id=. you have to use INNER JOIN to join both tables

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused; are you saying that if I want to display a list of duplicate values, I have to use an INNER join? I'm not sure what you mean by user id.

Comment: user_id is just a example. that you can JOIN 2 tables on a specific column if they are uniques. with that your query will be more accurate even if they duplicated. if you see accurary is ok by using 1 SELECT with LIMIT 1 then no problem. LIMIT 1 will only LIMIT the result to 1 SELECT it does not matter if there's 1000 results duplicated.

Comment: Yikes, I goofed. I just edited my post to remove the WHERE clause -- WHERE Combined.URL LIKE :XURL My goal is to query EVERYTHING. It doesn't make much sense to search for duplicates that match just one URL. ;)